# Jquery adding a required attribute on nearest element class

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to add a `require` attribute to a closest `textarea` when my radio field value is NO, I know you can target this specifically but my checklist has a 15 items and I don't want to repeat each function.

My code is below, I am able to get the value but it does not add a required attribute any of the closest `textarea`.

My HTML

```
<tr>
    <td width="10">1</td>
    <td width="650">Does the stencil follow the standard size?</td>
    <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="YES" required></label></td>
    <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="NO" class="noq"></label></td>
    <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="N/A"></label></td>
    <td><textarea rows='1' class='autoExpand' name="remarks_q1"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

My jQuery

```
$('.noq').on('click', function(e) {
    if(e.currentTarget.value == 'NO'){
        $(this).parent().closest('.autoExpand').prop('required',true);
    }else{
        $(this).parent().closest('.autoExpand').prop('required',false);
    }

    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
});
```

My console log give the correct value, I also tried the `prop` but no luck, any suggestion would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a `required` class to understand the change, also have added `.noq` class to radio buttons, as that was missing. And removed the `else` condition as that can be avoided. Instead of using `parent()`, you should be using `closes()` to get closest `tr`:

```js
$('.noq').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.autoExpand').prop('required', false).removeClass('required');
  if (e.currentTarget.value == 'NO') {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.autoExpand').prop('required', true).addClass('required');
  }
});
```

```css
.required {
  border: 1px solid #d00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="10">1</td>
      <td width="650">Does the stencil follow the standard size?</td>
      <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="YES" class="noq" required></label></td>
      <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="NO" class="noq"></label></td>
      <td width="10"><label><input type="radio" name="q1" class="noq" value="N/A"></label></td>
      <td><textarea rows='1' class='autoExpand' name="remarks_q1"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The JQuery closest method searches up the DOM tree, so you can't use it here to find the text area.

Try something like the below, which will search up the DOM tree to find the closest tr and then down the DOM tree to find your textarea.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.autoExpand').prop('required',true);
```